# Java Applet: painted ball does not appear in the hard-coded position. Applet does not maintain constant size

Tags: java, graphics, applet, coordinates

I'm making an applet consisting of a ball that moves across the screen.
I set the ball's initial X and Y co-ordinates to be 0, however the oval is drawn at some distance from these points (See image).
The other problem is that sometimes when I run the application, I get an applet with the desired width and height but at other times, it is smaller. I'm not sure why this happens.

[image: painted ball does not appear in hard coded position]

I've pasted the code below:

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.Timer;


public class StartingPoint extends Applet implements ActionListener
{
    final int DELAY             = 10;
    final int APPLET_WIDTH      = 400; 
    final int APPLET_HEIGHT     = 300;

    int x=0;
    int y=0;
    int ballRadius  = 20;
    int movementX   = 10;
    int movementY   = 10;

    private Image appletImage;
    private Graphics appletGraphics;

    public void init()
    {
        super.init();
        //StartingPoint.this.setSize( APPLET_WIDTH, APPLET_HEIGHT );
    }


    public void start() 
    {
        Timer animationTimer = new Timer(60, this);
        animationTimer.start();
    }

    public void stop()
    {
        super.stop();
    }

    public void destroy()
    {
        super.destroy();
    }


    public void update(Graphics g)
    {
        if(appletImage == null)
        {
            appletImage = createImage( this.getSize().width, this.getSize().height );
            appletGraphics = appletImage.getGraphics();
        }

        //draw applet background
        appletGraphics.setColor(getBackground());
        appletGraphics.fillRect(0, 0, this.getSize().width, this.getSize().height);

        //draw applet foreground
        appletGraphics.setColor(getForeground());
        this.paint( appletGraphics );

        //draw images on the applet
        g.drawImage(appletImage, 0, 0, this);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paint(g);
        this.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillOval(this.x, this.y, ballRadius, ballRadius);
    }


    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if( (x+movementX) > (this.getWidth()-ballRadius))
        {
            this.x = this.getWidth()-ballRadius;
            this.movementX = -movementX;
        }else if( x+movementX < ballRadius)
        {
            this.x = ballRadius;
            this.movementX = -movementX;
        }
        else
            this.x += movementX;

        if( (y+movementY) > this.getHeight()-ballRadius)
        {
            this.y = this.getHeight()-ballRadius;
            this.movementY = -movementY;
        }else if( y+movementY < ballRadius)
        {
            this.y = ballRadius;
            this.movementY = -movementY;
        }
        else
            this.y += movementY;


        this.repaint();
    }
}
```

Comment: Regarding the size: Since your program is an Applet, its size will be handled by the browser, not by the Applet itself. Are you using and IDE? In Eclipse, you can set the size of the Applet in the Run Configurations dialogue. I'm sure it's similar in other IDE's.

Comment: I don't think it's a very good idea to handle the animation with a while loop and a Sleep call. You should check out the Swing Timer class [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html)

Comment: Thanks so much for that tip :) Any idea about why the ball doesn't get drawn at 0,0?

Comment: [Updated code using a Swing Timer instead of `while(true)` inside Thread.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out where I went wrong and it really is kind of stupid.

These lines of code in the actionPerformed() method offset the x and y positions:

```
else
            this.x += movementX;

//....
else
            this.y += movementY;
```